# flutter build web command failing on linux machines after update 2.8.1

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-build

I am trying to build flutter web app on ubuntu machine with command "flutter build web". Build is getting failed with below stack-trace. It is occurring since Flutter update 2.8.1

I have tried it on local machine as well as on azure VM. I am getting same error. Code is getting built successfully on mac os machines. Actual stack-trace is too large to be posted here.

```
Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 77d935af4d (4 weeks ago) • 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
Engine • revision 890a5fca2e
Tools • Dart 2.15.1
/snap/bin/flutter
/snap/bin/dart
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...                       6.6s
Running "flutter pub get" in s...                                  17.8s

 Building with sound null safety 

Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...
Target dart2js failed: Exception: ../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus_windows-2.1.1/lib/src/device_info_plus_windows.dart:4:8:
Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi';
       ^
../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-1.1.2/lib/src/allocation.dart:5:8:
Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi';
       ^
../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-1.1.2/lib/src/arena.dart:8:8:
Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi';
       ^
../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-1.1.2/lib/src/utf8.dart:6:8:
Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi';
```